# Opengl - Creating a mini map from a gl view

Tags: android, opengl-es

I want to create a map from some opengl code that I wrote :

In order to do that I though about taking a screen shot of the upperview of the gl screen.
Yet I cant seem to find how to do that...

any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by taking a screenshot? You want to take a static picture or render a "view from above" on a different portion of the screen in realtime?

Comment: render a view from above

Comment: On way to achieve this is to setup your rendering state to the way you want the mini-map to look like (setup the viewport to be from above, and maybe use orthographic projection), then render it to a texture. Now you can put this texture in the corner of your screen or wherever you want it to be. The exact details about implementing this are depended on what framework you're using (plain OpenGL vs some other helper/library)

Answer (score -1):

Similar problem has been solved in [OSG example code here](https://github.com/xarray/osgRecipes/blob/master/cookbook/chapter4/ch04_05/four_views.cpp).

First you need to set your view such that you are looking at center from the TOP VIEW.

```
 osg::Vec3 center = scene->getBound().center();
    double radius = scene->getBound().radius();
    view->getCamera()->setViewMatrixAsLookAt( center - lookDir*(radius*3.0), center, up );
    view->getCamera()->setProjectionMatrixAsPerspective(
        30.0f, static_cast<double>(width)/static_cast<double>(height), 1.0f, 10000.0f );
```

Then, you need to use some OS specific API to do similar to [logic below](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/osg-users/94Ltb2eTF00):

```
osgViewer::ScreenCaptureHandler* scrn = new osgViewer::ScreenCaptureHandler();
osgViewer::ScreenCaptureHandler::WriteToFile* captureOper = new osgViewer::ScreenCaptureHandler::WriteToFile(tmpStr.m_szBuffer, "png");
scrn->setCaptureOperation(captureOper);
scrn->captureNextFrame(*_viewer); 
_viewer->frame();
```

Of course if you are not using OSG then you need to find equivalent APIs (of library you are using) to achieve the same task.

Comment: You absolutely do not need an "os specific api" to do this. Framebuffers are the way to go.

Comment: care to give actual API?

Comment: Lookup "opengl render to texture". Framebuffers involve a bit of setup, but are completely on the GPU; using the OS API to do a screenshot on the CPU side just to reupload it to the GPU is too inefficient when you're doing it every frame.